# How to remove data-saferedirecturl from email which is added automatically

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, html-email

I am sending email using php with download link to an exe file. But gmail adds data-saferedirecturl attribute to anchor tag which does not allows to download the file. If the url if copied paste in new tab download starts.

```
<a href="urlgoeshere" download data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=urlgoeshere&source=gmail&ust=1648747518176000&usg=AOvVaw1WTfnD2mM-yfsLTAChuqtT"> </a>
```

How do I stop this from happening

Comment: _"which does not allows to download the file"_ - that is probably due to the fact, that the `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs - and the context in which you are looking at this, is probably not a document loaded from `https://www.google.com/`. What happens when you simply remove that attribute?

Comment: I am not adding this attribute it is added automatically by Gmail i guess.

Answer (score 5):

Email providers are inserting your code into their website/app. They therefore have a layer of security *which changes your code*. They have to explicitly allow (whitelist) every bit of code and do things like the above to ensure security. There is often no way around it, for good reason.

I say "often", because sometimes there are workarounds. There is no known workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I disable the on-click tracking from SendGrid, and it worked, I assume you're also using some sort of email sender, try to check the on-click tracking setting from your email sender provider.
Thanks