# Text with dot automatically converting to URL

Tags: postmark

I am using postmark to send emails by providing HtmlBody.
My text contains dot like this

> Hello user.com

When mail is sent, `user.com` converts to URL.

Is there any way to prevent such automatic conversion (adding space is not an option)?

Comment: data-saferedirecturl was added by gmail. more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71681657/how-to-remove-data-saferedirecturl-from-email-which-is-added-automatically

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar on Slack, and the only workaround I found was to replace the dots with "fake dots".

> The fake dot looks like a regular dot but will usually not be
> recognized as a link and therefore not be converted to a clickable
> link.
>
> I haven’t found a way to easily type it on the keyboard, so you can
> copy the fake dot from here  ->    ․
>
> The fake dot is technically the Unicode character called ONE DOT
> LEADER (U+2024). The regular period is FULL STOP (U+022E) {period,
> dot, decimal point}.

Source - [Prevent clickable links with a fake dot](https://blog.onevinn.com/prevent-clickable-links-with-a-fake-dot) by Tom Aafloen